# How to handle with Wordpress scripts actions mess?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

During developing Wordpress + BuddyPress child theme I came across the problem with scripts.
I want to move them to BODY footer (except Modernizr), but some BuddyPress script stay on the top. I heve made it:

```
// remove unused head entries
remove_action('wp_head',        'rsd_link');
//...
remove_action('wp_head',        'adjacent_posts_rel_link');

// move sctipts to footer
remove_action('wp_head',        'wp_print_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head',        'wp_print_head_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head',        'wp_enqueue_scripts');
remove_action('wp_head',        'bp_core_confirmation_js');
remove_action('wp_head',        'bp_core_add_ajax_url_js');

add_action('wp_head',           'wp_head_scripts',      9);
add_action('wp_footer',         'wp_enqueue_scripts',           20);
add_action('wp_footer',         'bp_core_confirmation_js',      21);
add_action('wp_footer',         'bp_core_add_ajax_url_js',      22);
```

I'm confused with action order and it doesn't look pretty.

Is it possible to make it prettier (more automatic)? I thinking about an array like this:

```
$head_scripts = array(
    'modernizr'         => 'libs/modernizr-2.6.1.js',
);
$footer_scripts = array(
    'jquery'            => 'libs/jquery-1.8.2.js',
    'jquery.mansonry'   => 'libs/jquery.masonry.min.js',
    'fb_api'            => 'libs/fb_api.js',
    'scripts'           => 'script.js'
);
```

and one function (action), which add first in the head, other in the footer and next admin_bar, buddypress scripts if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you track all those script `wp_enqueue_script` file and change the in_footer parameter to true. As you may know that the wp_enqueue_script method has the last parameter which you can indicate whether that script will be placed into the footer. The default is false which will be put into the header

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 
        $handle
       ,$src
       ,$deps
       ,$ver
       ,$in_footer  // make this TRUE to put the script in the footer
);
```

For more info visit the doc http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: Ok. I know it, but BuddyPress and other plugins sripts stay in head.
How to get controll all of these script in one place. F.e. for concat/compress it into one in production version.

I'm new with WP hooks.